# Добавление данных в Postgresql с помощью Dapper в Asp.net core

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, dapper

Мой код:

```
 public async Task<int> CreateAsync(Employe entity)
        {
            try
            {
                var query = "INSERT INTO public.\"Employees\"(\"Name\", \"Surname\", \"Phone\", \"CompanyId\", \"Pass_Type\", \"Pass_Number\", \"Dep_Name\", \"Dep_Phone\") VALUES (@Name, @Surname, @Phone,@CompanyId,@Passport.Type,@Passport.Number,@Department.Name,@Department.Phone)";

                var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
                parameters.Add("Name", entity.Name, DbType.String);
                parameters.Add("Surname", entity.Surname, DbType.String);
                parameters.Add("Phone", entity.Phone, DbType.String);
                parameters.Add("CompanyId", entity.Companyid, DbType.Int32);
                parameters.Add("Pass_Type", entity.Passport.Type, DbType.String);
                parameters.Add("Pass_Number", entity.Passport.Number, DbType.String);
                parameters.Add("Dep_Name", entity.Department.Name, DbType.String);
                parameters.Add("Dep_Phone", entity.Department.Phone, DbType.String);


                using (var connection = CreateConnection())
                {
                    return (await connection.ExecuteAsync(query, parameters));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex);
            }
        }
```

В swagger получаю ошибку:
**System.Exception: 42P01: таблица "passport" отсутствует в предложении FROM**

Comment: Вы уверены, что ошибка именно здесь? Как вы это поняли?

Comment: @aepot Скорее всего, потому-что в debug останавливается на 
return (await connection.ExecuteAsync(query, parameters));  и ecxeption

Comment: Вот вы устанавливаете `parameters.Add("Pass_Type"`, но у вас нет в запросе `@Pass_Type`. С другими параметрами то же самое.